# Service for get parameters from yml

Tags: php, symfony, service

i have a problem with service for get parameters from yml file in symfony. Now my service looks like very simple.

```
class MyService extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $keys;

    public function __construct($keys)
    {
        $this->keys = $keys;
    }

    public function getKeys()
    {
        return $this->keys;
    }

}
```

And in Controller method:

```
 public function exampleAction()
    {
        $keys = new MyService('keys');
        return var_dump($this->getParameter($keys->getKeys()));

    }
```

But when i try to add getParameter function in service (look at code under this text) it's not work.
Service:

```
class MyService extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $keys;

    public function __construct($keys)
    {
        $this->keys = $keys;
    }

    public function getKeys()
    {
        return $this->getParameter($this->keys);
    }

}
```

And Controller:

```
public function exampleAction()
    {
        $keys = new MyService('keys');
         return var_dump($keys->getKeys());

    }
```

Someone can tell me what's wrong?
Thx :)

Comment: You should not create your service with `new` keyword but use the DIC to wire it up. You can pass your parameters there.

Comment: Are you using the Symfony frameworks or just a few components?  If you are using the framework then you approach is fundamentally flawed and you should review the service container section in the docs.  The answers below are trying to make sense of your posted code but you are pretty much on the wrong track completely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your parameter structure but you can take this as an example. if you want to access

> yourKey

.

```
parameters:
    key:
        yourKey: bar
        bar: baz

$params = $this->getParameter('bar');
$yourKey = $params['yourKey'];
```

you can learn more about YAML here [The Yaml Component](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/yaml.html)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are mentioning that this is a service, it is actually a `controller`. (Because your services extends the `controller`). I don't think that is the best approach.

However, because you are in a `controller` and having not mentioned about any sort of `DI` you can do like this.

```
public function __construct(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function getKeys()
{
    return $this->container->getParameter('keys');
}
```

**For your attention,**

However, if you are using `DI`. Do not inject the whole `container` as it has lots of performance drawbacks. Only pass the required parameters.

Thank you.